# C++ does the integer size matter when using bitfields?

Tags: c++, bit-fields

Other than signed or unsigned, to what degree does the type matter for bitfields, if at all?

For example what is the difference between:

```
unsigned char a : 3;
std::uint64_t b : 3;
```

I'm guessing as long as the bitfield is not larger than the type, it doesn't matter.

Comment: It affects the size of the struct or class it's declared in: https://godbolt.org/z/1broTWxsY

Comment: well `a` needs 1 byte, and `b` needs 8.

Comment: It's implementation defined.  It might affect the allocation unit size used for the bitfield or it might not.

Comment: It is implementation-defined how it affects the layout of the containing type.   However, accessing the value of `yourbitfield.a` in your example (where `yourbitfield` is an instance of the type that contains the two bitfileds you describe) will produce a result of `unsigned char` and accessing `yourbitfield.b` will produce a result of type `std::uint64_t`.    So `x = yourbitfield.a` will extract the field `a` as an `unsigned char`, and promote that to the type of `x` to do the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the compiler to decide how to lay out those values. The resulting object must be large enough to hold values that fit in the number of bits for the bitfield. For example, `struct { std::unit64_t b : 8 }` can be 8 bits in size; it is not required to be large enough to hold 64 bits.

But each bitfield has a type, and the type can affect the program's behavior. Here's a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(char) {
    std::cout << "char\n";
}

void f(int) {
    std::cout << "int\n";
}
struct a {
    char a : 3;
    int b : 3;
};

int main()
{
    a obj;
    f(obj.a);
    f(obj.b);
    return 0;
}
```

The (fully portable) output is:

```
[temp]$ clang++ test.cpp
[temp]$ ./a.out
char
int
[temp]$
```

Answer (score 0):

> C++ does the integer size matter when using bitfields?

Yes, it does.

> For example what is the difference between:
>
> ```
> unsigned char a : 3;
> std::uint64_t b : 3;
> ```

The type of the first bit field is `unsigned char` and the type of the other bit field is `std::uint64_t`. On most systems these types have a different size.

> Does that have any practical effect

Here is a simple example demonstrating a practical effect:

```
struct a {
    unsigned char a : 3;
};

struct b {
    std::uint64_t b : 3;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << ' ' << sizeof(b);
}
```

Comment: Does that have any practical effect when the bitfield limits them to 3 bits each?

Comment: Each bitfield in that example is 3 bits wide. They are not required to take up more than 3 bits each.